# How do I remove all ACLS in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, acl

I've tried the following and it doesn't work, although in theory, according to the acl tool tip it should work.

```
kafka-acls --bootstrap-server server:9094 --command-config client-sasl.properties --remove --allow-principal User:* --operation * --topic * --resource-pattern-type literal
```

Comment: You may need to quote each of the `*` to prevent shell globbing

Comment: @OneCricketeer I've also tried any every combination wih quotes, without quotes, .*, '.*'. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: When I worked with ACLs, we used Apache Ranger rather than Zookeeper, so I don't have any other suggestions here... Maybe using `zkCli` you can delete whole znodes, but I dont know if Kafka brokers would be happy about you doing that , assuming they maintain some other state